# Loopcount in assembly code issue

Tags: loops, assembly, x86

My program is stuck in a loop, can anyone see why?

Basically I want to take an user input to determine how many times to loop and then the user enters their desired values (positive or negative numbers). They will then be compared against 0. If the number is positive then add it to positive stack address if negative then put it to negative stack address and print the result..

```
  mov ecx, loopvalue

l1:
  push ecx
  lea eax, getvalue 
  push eax 
  call printf 
  add esp, 4 
  lea eax, uservalue 
  push eax 

  lea eax,format 
  push eax
  call scanf_s 
  add esp, 4 
  pop ecx
  loop l1
```

Comment: You push 4 times, and pop/advance esp only 3, something's not balanced here

Comment: Thankyou! i have fixed the loop with the stack now, however now when it runs through past the loop and goes to print out the results the print line isn't hanging and the command prompt is exiting the program after the loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supplying `scanf_s` with 2 arguments on the stack but you're not freeing both arguments on the stack after the call (you're only adding 4). You should instead add 8 to correct this:

```
lea eax, uservalue 
push eax 

lea eax,format 
push eax
call scanf_s 
add esp, 8
```

Comment: @user2968561 Don't forget to accept if this solves your issue.